Big two sided arrow across matrix
How to get big two sided arrow across the matrix?
\begin{equation}
A_{\text{mux}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_0 & & \\
& \ddots & \\
& & A_{2^{n_c}-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
\updownarrow{2^n} \\
\vdots \\
\updownarrow{2^n} \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
 \begin{array}{c} \\ \\ \end{array} \updownarrow {2^{n+n_c}} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The above code is giving arrow like below:

I want arrow like as shown below:


\updownarrow is a growing delimiter, not a command with argument.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left. % to balance the last \right
A_{\mathrm{mux}} = % <--- NOT \text
\begin{bmatrix}
A_0 & & \\
& \ddots & \\
& & A_{2^{n_c}-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\;
\begin{matrix}
\updownarrow 2^n \\
\vdots \\
\updownarrow 2^n \\
\end{matrix}
\;
\right\updownarrow 2^{n+n_c}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


